# Swift NSManagedObject Subclass Incorrectly Adds Module Name on 10.13 and Below

Tags: swift, cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobject

## Context

I'm building an app on macOS Catalina (10.15.6) using Xcode 12. The app uses Core Data. I've let Xcode generate subclasses of my NSManagedObject entities using Swift. Those look like this:

```
// LPProject+CoreDataClass.swift

import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(LPProject)
public class LPProject: NSManagedObject
{
    @objc func printStuff() {
        NSLog("This is a function to test the situation.")
    }
}
```

And the other auto-generated file:

```
// LPProject+CoreDataProperties.swift

import Foundation
import CoreData

extension LPProject {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<LPProject> {
        return NSFetchRequest<LPProject>(entityName: "LPProject")
    }

}
```

I have omitted the properties of the entity because they are not relevant to the problem.

---

## The Problem

Part of my app is still Objective-C. In that part, I create an `LPProject` entity and attempt to call `printStuff()`:

```
// Assume 'moc' is an NSManagedObjectContext defined elsewhere.

LPProject *project = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"LPProject" inManagedObjectContext:moc];

[project printSomeStuff];
```

**On macOS 10.14.6 and 10.15, this works perfectly.** On older versions, it produces an "Unrecognized Selector" crash:

```
-[NSManagedObject printStuff]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x01038202384929
```

This happens because the module name is prepended to the class name. I see this log message:

```
warning: Unable to load class named 'MyApp.LPProject' for entity 'LPProject'.
Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.
```

According to everything I can find, the entity is configured properly in the Core Data editor to work with the `@objc()` declaration:

[image]

So...what am I missing? Why is the module name prepended to the class name on 10.14.5 and below but not on 10.14.6+?

Comment: Update: Running the 'otool -ov' command on the compiled binary on macOS 10.13 shows that the ObjC class and the -printStuff method **ARE** defined. (That makes sense, because if they were not, the crash would happen on 10.14 and 10.15, too, and compiler would throw an error.) The cause seems to be that, for some reason, Core Data on 10.13 isn't returning the proper entity.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a LOT of things, including these based on other SO answers:

1. Remove the `@obc(LPProject)` attribute and use `@objc LPProject` instead. That fixed macOS 10.11 -> 10.13, but broke Lightweight Migration on 10.14 and 10.15.
2. Remove the "Module" for all entities in Xcode's Model Editor and allow Core Data to use the global namespace. This broke modern macOS and is against Apple's latest guidelines.

---

## The Gist

Core Data on macOS 10.14.6+ resolves `MyApp.LPProject` to find the class `LPProject` and thus instantiate the correct NSManagedObject subclass. On older macOS versions, however, Core Data fails to connect these two, so instead of instantiating an `LPProject` object, it falls back to a generic `NSManagedObject` object.

Therefore, on macOS 10.14.5 and below, we must TELL Core Data that the damn class name for the entity named "LPProject" is `LPProject` instead of `MyApp.LPProject`. We must repeat this for each entity in our model. To do that, we can hijack the model-loading point:

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *) managedObjectModel 
{
    if (_managedObjectModel) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"myDataFile" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    
    if (@available(macOS 10.14.6, *))
    {
        // Do nothing; not needed
    }
    else
    {
        NSArray<NSEntityDescription*> *entities = [_managedObjectModel entities];
        NSMutableArray *fixedEntities = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:entities.count];

        for (NSEntityDescription *des in entities)
        {
            if ([des.managedObjectClassName hasPrefix:@"MyApp."] && des.managedObjectClassName.length > 6) 
            {
                NSString *fixedName = [des.managedObjectClassName substringFromIndex:6];
                des.managedObjectClassName = fixedName;
            }
            [fixedEntities addObject:des];
        }
        
        [_managedObjectModel setEntities:fixedEntities];
    }
    
    return _managedObjectModel;
}
```

---

## Result

The above solves the problem completely. On old macOS versions, Core Data now correctly finds the right NSManagedObject subclass for each entity. It also works on modern macOS versions. Lightweight migration continues to work on all versions as well.

Note: This approach is used with the `@objc(LPProject)` attribute in an NSManagedObject subclass (as auto-generated by Xcode 12) AND setting each entity's "Module" to "Current Product Module" in the Core Data Model Editor GUI in Xcode.

Note 2: I have no idea if this is sane. It has all the hallmarks of an ugly hack, but (A) it WORKS and (B) it makes no changes to anything on macOS 10.14.6+, which is the majority of users.

Note 3: If you use this, be sure to adjust the `6` to the count of characters in YOUR module name (including the period). Otherwise, you'll have a bad day.

Comment: Note: The issue appears on macOS 10.14.5 and below, so I've updated my answer with the correct macOS version to target.